# Server doesn't start in hello world app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Django hello world app.

I have the following code:

```
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='badkey',
    ROOT_URLCONF=sys.modules[__name__],
)

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World')

urlpatterns = [
    (r'^hello-world/$', index),
]
```

Located at `/smartQuiz/smartQuiz/hello.py`, where `smartQuiz` is the root directory of my project.

If I run `python hello.py runserver` from the directory where `hello.py` is located, the server won't start.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That really isn't how you run Django. What gave you the idea that this would work?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I'm not getting any message. I was looking here: https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/create-the-hello-world-web-app/

Comment: If you follow the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) you will see how it should be done.

Comment: That is a *very* weird tutorial. Nevertheless, looks like you missed step 6. But really, don't do this; follow the proper tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
```

Here is a full minimal example previously written by [minigunnr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3127653/minigunnr) on the Stack Overflow documentation:

> This example shows you a minimal way to create a Hello World page in Django. This will help you realize that the django-admin startproject example command basically creates a bunch of folders and files and that you don't necessarily need that structure to run your project.
>
> 1. Create a file called file.py.
> 2. Copy and paste the following code in that file.
>
>    ```
>    import sys
>
>    from django.conf import settings
>
>    settings.configure(
>        DEBUG=True,
>        SECRET_KEY='thisisthesecretkey',
>        ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
>        MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
>            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
>        ),
>    )
>
>    from django.conf.urls import url
>    from django.http import HttpResponse
>
>    # Your code goes below this line.
>
>    def index(request):
>        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
>
>    urlpatterns = [
>        url(r'^$', index),
>    ]
>
>    # Your code goes above this line
>
>    if __name__ == "__main__":
>        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>
>        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>    ```
> 3. Go to the terminal and run the file with this command `python file.py runserver`.
> 4. Open your browser and go to 127.0.0.1:8000.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to directly call hello.py with runserver as an argument.
If you are writing and trying to test Django, make sure that you are using the framework to start the server.  It will take care of all the 'Django stuff' required:
`python manage.py runserver`
manage.py takes care of setting things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it the wrong way.
[Use this link to know how to make a django app](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)